# Change User sign-in to federated in AD Connect

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs

In our environment someone have changed the user Sign-in method to Password Hash through synchronization from federated with ADFS, although it did not have any impact as users are still authenticating with ADFS succesfully. But now we need to change it back to Federated with ADFS. There is not much documentation on what will be impact or if the trust and claims will be modified if we change it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is a [simple switch](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5367fb9e-6524-4188-8266-c42b917b8b06/office-365-switch-from-password-hash-sync-to-federation-with-adfs).

Note the point about cache issues.

And always good to have backups!

Comment: As per MS documentation it will modify the trust and claims in ADFS, so what will happen to the trust and claims which are already there for Azure AD.